# Writing to and creating a file in Python using uWSGI

Tags: python, nginx, io, wsgi

I have an app on a server that is set up to use uWSGI and nginx. The app works fine locally, but on the server it doesn't seem to have the ability to create files from the program. I believe I set the directory permissions correctly. This is the output of `ls` on the directory the application is stored in:

```
drwxrwxr-x 6 ben 4.0K May 15 21:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 ben 4.0K May 15 20:33 ..
drwxrwxr-x 8 ben 4.0K May 15 21:01 .git
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ben 5.1K May 15 21:01 albumcloud.py
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ben 5.4K May 15 21:01 albumcloud.pyc
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ben  248 May 15 20:32 lyricloud.ini
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ben 1.7K May 15 21:01 lyricloud.py
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ben 2.6K May 15 21:01 lyricloud.pyc
srwxrwxr-x 1 ben    0 May 15 21:01 lyricloud.sock
drwxrwxr-x 6 ben 4.0K May 14 23:32 lyricloudenv
drwxrwxr-x 2 ben 4.0K May 15 20:37 static
drwxrwxr-x 2 ben 4.0K May 15 20:32 templates
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ben   94 May 15 20:32 wsgi.py
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ben  245 May 15 20:33 wsgi.pyc
```

The user `ben` is part of the `www-data` group that nginx runs under.

The script should be writing text files to the static directory, but no files are ever created. The project code can be found [here](https://github.com/benfb/albumcloud).

uWSGI is being launched by a script at /etc/init/lyricloud.conf

```
description "uWSGI server instance configured to serve lyricloud"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid ben
setgid www-data
env PATH=/home/ben/lyricloud/lyricloudenv/bin
chdir /home/ben/lyricloud
exec uwsgi --ini lyricloud.ini
```

Comment: What user is the uwsgi processes being run under?

Comment: The only ``open()`` call I see that has ``mode="w"`` in your [code](https://github.com/benfb/albumcloud/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=open) is commented out. Is that because it's not working and throwing errors?

Comment: The writing command is `f = open(os.path.join(here,"static/" + id + ".txt"), 'w')` in albumcloud.py

Comment: Indeed; What errors do you get? There has to be errors being thrown; things generally don't silently fail :)

Comment: I'm actually not sure where the error log is. The wsgi log doesn't give any errors and I'm not sure where the python log is located. There is one error in the nginx logs: `[error] 1181#0: *203 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream` but it doesn't seem particularly relevant

Comment: Run uwsgi by hand by running: ``uwsgi --ini --honour-stdin /path/to/uwsgi.ini`` and possibly insert a ``import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and debug it :)

Comment: That fails with `realpath() of --honor-stdin failed: No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3368]` Is there some place to set the log path?

Comment: If I let uwsgi run like it has been and add the debugger, it crashes with bdb.BdbQuit